# New to Tailwind CSS, how do I get my Tailwind to display to my simple webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css, tailwind-3

I'm new to Tailwind CSS (first project) and I feel like I'm missing a basic step in getting my Tailwind to work properly.

I have my Project Folder Structure:

Lesson01

- build (folder)
   
    css (folder)
    
       style.css
    
       index.html
- src
   
     input.css
   
     tailwind.config.js

I'm trying to make an emerald colored div box with some different classes applied for shadows and making the object a full circle. Nothing too crazy yet.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
</head>

<body class="min-h-screen grid place-content-center">
  <div class="bg-emerald-500 w-52 h-52 rounded-full shadow-2xl"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

tailwind.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ['./build/*.html'],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

style.css is the output of the generated base Tailwind css file.

input.css contains the initial layers for Tailwind CSS

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

I'm new to Tailwind but I would love to learn and apply it for my home projects that I'm experimenting with. Any advice would be much appreciated!

I tried running

```
npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./build/css/style.css --watch
```

in the terminal to update the `style.css` file using the `input.css` file.

However, I didn't see any expected results. I did get hit with this:

```
Rebuilding...

warn - No utility classes were detected in your source files. If this is unexpected, double-check the `content` option in your Tailwind CSS configuration.
warn - https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration

Done in 58ms.
```

So the issues I'm hitting are for sure due to my noviceness with Tailwind haha.

Any help would be appreciated and I'm new to posting on StackOverflow as well!

Comment: Well, you really do need to double-check your `content` -- with that folder structure, `content` should be `["../build/css/*.html"]`...

Comment: Thank you AKX! I went ahead and restarted my project and was able to get it functioning as intended. It definitely came down to my project structure and the init process when I was setting it up initially.

Answer (score 0):

Tailwind is not using the configuration file at `src/tailwind.config.js` that you might be expecting. By default, Tailwind looks for a configuration file in the root of the project. For solutions, you could:

- Move the `src/tailwind.config.js` file to the root of your project.
- Load your `src/tailwind.config.js` via the [`@config` directive](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#config) in your `src/input.css` file:

  ```css
  @config "./tailwind.config.js";

  @tailwind base;
  @tailwind components;
  @tailwind utilities;
  ```

Also, you state your `index.html` is in `build/css/index.html` so you'd need to add this to your `content`:

```js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './build/*.html',
    './build/css/index.html',
  ],
```

And fix the path to the CSS file in `index.html`:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
```

Comment: Thank you Wongjn! I followed your steps and realized that I had my folder structure and init sequence wrong from the jump. I went ahead and deleted my project, remade it, and now everything is working as intended.

Thank you again for your help!